# how to write a session method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

i want to write method just like `public User getUserFromSession()`,`private void setUserInSession(User user)`. I want when a user logins, it can save his information. I try but failed, I work with spring-mvc, I want to write the method for `getUserFromSession` and `setUserInSession`, when I use anoher controller, I can call `getUserFromSession()`, I can get the user info. How to do it?

My login controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public ModelAndView loginCheck(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String userName = request.getParameter("j_username");
    String userPwd = request.getParameter("j_password");

    boolean isValidUser = populator.loginCheck(userName, userPwd);
    if (!isValidUser) {
        return new ModelAndView("auth/loginpage", "error", "name or password error!");
    } else {
        request.setAttribute("j_username", userName);
        return new ModelAndView("auth/main");
    }

}
```

my service

```
    @Transactional
public boolean loginCheck(String userName, String password) {
    boolean rtn = false;
    log.debug(userName);

    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(userName)) {
        User loginUser = template.lookup(User.class, "login", userName).to(User.class).singleOrNull();

        if (loginUser != null) {

            String userPassword = loginUser.getPassword();

            if (new Md5PasswordEncoder().encodePassword(password, User.SALT).equals(userPassword)) {

                rtn = true;
                //setUserInSession(loginUser);
                //log.debug( "====== loginCheck getUserFromSession ===="+getUserFromSession());
            }
        }
    } else {
        log.warn("you must input user name");
    }

    return rtn;

}
public User getUserFromSession();
private void setUserInSession(User user) ;
```

Comment: Why are you wanting to write it yourself?

Comment: So you want a method to wrap `HttpSession session = request.getSession(false); session.setAttribute("user", yourUserObject);` and another to wrap `HttpSession session = request.getSession(false); session.getAttribute("user");`?

Comment: er..this works well,but when i need the session,i should write all of them,i have many controller need call it so i want to abstract it a class,and when i use it ,just call the class,

Comment: Just use Spring Security man. MD5 password encoding? C'mon

Comment: If you want customisation - then pick up these guide http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.x/guides/form.html

Answer (score 0):

Why not manage the spring way

```
<bean id="userInfoBean" class="com.fwk.session.UserInfoImpl" scope="session">
     <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false"/>
</bean>
```

Keeps all information of bean for that user and works the spring way.